# Clear Theme/CSS Cache in Magento 2

Tags: cache, css, frontend, magento2, development

When I am theming a Magento 2 store, what is the suggested way to clean the caches?

I edit the `.less` files and then I currently do

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* var/view_preprocessed/ var/*cache/*
```

But this seems to be the brute-force method.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush --all
```

seems to not do the job.

Is there a better one?

Comment: since your question still as unresolved, please take a look at my answer here:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/101139/27685, I think could  help.

Comment: I'm also having a lot of problems with CSS/Less being cached, manually deleting the changed module in pub/static sometimes helps but not always. M2 is proving difficult to work with

Answer (score 18):

I think right way to refresh .less files now it's

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Because it "Collects, processes and publishes source LESS files"

Another point it's use dev mode during development then according to [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html) "Static view files are not cached; they are written to the Magento pub/static directory every time they’re called"

To set Magento 2 to Developer mode you need to do following steps

1. Delete the contents of the var/generation and var/di directories:

   `rm -rf <your Magento install dir>/var/di/* <your Magento install dir>/var/generation/*`
2. Set the mode:

   `php bin/magento  setup:mode:set developer`

Comment: there is no such `deploy:mode:set` command anymore (beta2). But I set `MAGE_MODE` via `SetEnv`. For `dev:css:deploy` I have to enter a file name. Which should I use?

Comment: sorry, this was my bad. setup:static-content:deploy is correct command for do that. also deploy:mode:set seems like still works for me, you are not have it in command list of bin/magento as well?

Comment: got it, deploy:mode:set was changed also to setup:mode:set according to https://goo.gl/Pive1U

Comment: I am still trying this stuff...

Comment: "Static view files are not cached; they are written to the Magento pub/static directory every time they’re called" I think the doc is wrong. There is a `RewriteCond !-f` in the `.htaccess` in `pub/static` which makes Apache to use the cached version if it exists.

Comment: If you only want to recompile LESS files into CSS, then the proper command is `magento dev:source-theme:deploy` ([reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html)). `magento setup:static-content:deploy` takes a very long time and is not practical if you are developing and making frequent changes to LESS files.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to clear the css cache, if the changes are not reflecting.

**1. Use Grunt instead so you don't need to clean cache after every change of css (recommended way), you can see more documentation about grunt from [check this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)**

**2. Go to system > Cache Management > Additional Cache Management > Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache.**

[image]

**3. Run the deploy command (this takes a long and not a good recommendation, also change the mode to developer if it,s not there.)**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `pub/static` contents (in dev mode) are generated with the same logic that is used for `var/generation` files, i mean, if the required content does not exists then is created but if already exist is reused.

So I think that you should clean `pub/static[area]` too or run `setup:static-content:deploy` to override all but this process is very slow to run every time you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

In developer mode, instead of manually clear the `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed`.

Go to `System > Tools > Cache Management` and click **Flush Static Files Cache**.

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
grunt clean
```

or with more accuracy

```
grunt clean:<theme_name>
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#grunt_commands

Answer (score 0):

To flush magento cache in command like you can run:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

To flush storage cache you can run:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

To check status of the cache run (status should be on 1 for active and 0 for disabled):

```
bin/magento cache:status
```

To disable magento cache all together run:

```
bin/magento cache:disable
```

To enable cache run:

```
bin/magento cache:enable
```

But I think your issue resides in Magento mode being set on production mode. You can check your mode by using: `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` 
You can read more about magento production and developer mode [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html)

As a alternative for developer mode on `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` you can use `bin/magento setup:upgrade` it clears compiled code and the cache. Or simply manually delete anything form the `pub/static` folder of your project that you need updated. If something is missing from that folder will be re-generated with latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to CSS/LESS files modifications in custom themes, it looks like this one works pretty well to get the fresh version:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```