# Apply css change on M2

Tags: css, magento2

**Magento 2** use `less/php` lib to compile **less** to **css**
first run time i created my style named `style.less` in theme directory`(web/css)`. **Magento 2** compiled my file to `pub/static/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/en_US/css/style.css` then I edit `style.less` browser reload nothing change
How to apply new change on `style.less` when edit file? `command dev:css:deploy not work`

Comment: try putting your file in `web/css/source` and naming it `module.less` or `_module.less`

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82166/clear-theme-css-cache-in-magento-2

Comment: Do you enable Developer Mode? (you can use bin/magento deploy:mode:show to get current mode and  bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer to set)

Comment: I understand every dev, that does not see this as an option. M2 shipps in "static" mode, which is pretty neat to develop in. "Developer" mode is pretty slow and "Production" mode is hard to update. But the biggest flaw is, that once you change from "static" mode there is no way back. After that you can only change to "Production" or "Development". This is just a bad joke.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to configure compilation of style in admin path given below

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Front-end development workflow
```

change to

```
Client side less compilation
```

Then edit your theme styles module wise and other `web/css/source` (common style)

```
app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name
```

run below command to set developer mode

```
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

and clear cache and deploy static-content

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

This page in the Magento 2 documentation pretty well covers using Grunt to compile less. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html