# How can I compile less file in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I install magento2 in my system and its work properly but when i changed in less files then it's not affect in frontend.
then how can i compile `less files` in magento2 for get css effect in frontend.

Comment: You need switch to dev mode or run deploy of static, check this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/82168/2282

Comment: No, its not solve my problem.

Comment: WHY does it not solve your problem? What is different? Please explain exactly what your problem is, what you expect and what doesn't happen as expected

Comment: @fireBear :- if i have 4 theme and i did the changes in 1st theme and when i do deploy static content it do for all theme it waste of time   i have to wait but i need to do for only one theme , in that case how to do it

Comment: In developer mode: remove the `var/view_preprocessed` folder and the `css` file from `pub/static/...` and just clear the cache. The css will be regenerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page in the Magento 2 documentation pretty well covers using Grunt to compile less. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: link are bad answers. There is no information to answer the question in your answer.

Comment: Better docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html#server-side — note that you can compile the files either using PHP (using the built-in PHP less compiler) or Node.js (using gulp, grunt, etc.).