# Magento 2: How can I deploy my theme only

Tags: magento2, deploy, static-content

I was using this for deploy the content but it is taking too much time.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

then I figure out adding the language make fast but it still deploy all the themes.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  en_US
```

How can i  `deploy` only my theme content only?

Comment: FYI there is a [PR](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/4294) that will add this capability and a lot more. I think it'll probably come out with v2.2.

Comment: Another potential solution but for production mode http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126270/magento-2-deploy-static-files-for-specific-theme-only/126340

Comment: I am using magento 2.0.4 and using this <code>php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Rws/fonddecave en_US de_DE fr_FR</code>
But error is coming --theme option does not exists. What is my mistake can any one help on this?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153912)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153912)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153912)

Comment: Hello Qaisar. If you are reading this, I urge you to please accept Matthew's answer as the currently accepted answer is now out dated. This will better serve the community for others that stumble upon this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @DarrenFelton done.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As of 2.1.1 you can now deploy specific themes or exclude themes:

Deploy specific themes:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend --theme Vendor/mytheme
```

Exclude themes:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --exclude-theme Magento/luma
```

[image]

**Update** these options are now in [the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict).

Comment: it didn't work for me  also it didn't mention in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict 

There we just 2 options.

Comment: @AdeelIshfaq Like so many other things, it is not yet documented, but it does work in 2.1.1. I attached a screenshot.

Comment: Submitted a pull request to have the new options added to the documentation: https://github.com/magento/devdocs/pull/827

Comment: @MathewTinsley, is it possible to deploy a specific frontend theme in all languages, and a specific backend theme only in one language? I don't need my backend in all languages..

Comment: @bpoiss there is a `--language` Parameter now. Example `--language en_US`

Answer (score 27):

I'm afraid that you just can't deploy only one theme by magento console `setup:static-content:deploy` command.

I've been dealing with M2 frontend development for the last 2 weeks and I can affirm that the dev process it's a real PAIN! You'll lost a lot of time deploying changes due to complexity of less files hierarchy and themes fallbacks.

Anyway I'm Grunt by now [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html) you'll find how to install, configure and use it, with Grunt you can deploy and/or recompile less files for a single theme.

So that approach it's ok if you are in "developer" mode because Grunt doesn't deploy *images*, *fonts* and *javascript* files to `pub/static/...` so magento will do it the first time required.

> To activate developer mode, run:
>
> ```
> php bin/magento  deploy:mode:set developer
> ```

If you are looking for a way to deploy the entire content for a single theme in `production` I sorry to say that isn't possible.

BTW I'm pretty sure that it would be a nice *Feature Request* to make.

**EDIT: Breaking News!**

I found a way to deploy all changes a little faster:

- Install Grunt + config your theme *(one for each language)*
- after each change run:

  - `grunt exec:{theme_name} // Clean folders and deploy less files`
  - `grunt less:{theme_name} // Process less files`

Voila now you'll have all your changes deployed in *Just(¿?)* 12~16 sec, 12 sec is my personal record!

**EDIT: Breaking News 2!**

*Confirmed!* if you are making changes to a (already deployed) .less files just run `grunt less:{theme_name}`.

So, you have to run `grunt exec:{theme_name}`only when:

- Add/Remove/Rename a `*.less` File
- Add/Remove/Rename a `*.js` Fils
- Add/Remove/Rename a `*.css` File
- Add/Remove/Rename a `image` File
- Add/Remove `requirejs-config.js`

Additionally I disabled `blocks`, `layouts` and `full page` Caches, so any change to templates and/or xml layouts will be displayed automatically.

Comment: can you guid me how to make change in css through less i am stuck in topmenu. some item found but some are not but there css is there.. like `.nav-sections` child `level0`.

Comment: It's a very large topic I recommend you to read (the entire) official guide (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html). you must understand all `lib > module > theme > fallback.`  As a starting point take a look at `lib/web/css`

Comment: You can see the UI Library documentation in your own store or here: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/docs/index.html as well

Comment: What about when you edit a JS plugin? I found out that the changes were not getting reflected on the site. I had to remove the edited JS file from `pub/static` and redeploy (`setup:static-content:deploy`) for the changes to show.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer, the one below is much better.

Comment: actually you can use --theme vendor/theme to deploy a specific theme

Answer (score 18):

In Magento 2 you are able to content deploy specific themes and also exclude themes by this commands:

**Content Deploy specific themes** By this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Vendor/firsttheme --theme Vendor/secondtheme
```

**Exclude themes** By this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --exclude-theme Vendor/yourtheme
```

If you need deploys static content for **particular language (en_US)**, and exclude other theme, and need **not minify HTML files** then use this command:

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US --exclude-theme Vendor/yourtheme --no-html-minify
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is shortcut to deploy only your theme

> -a for area
>
> -t for theme
>
> -l for language

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -l en_US -a frontend -t Magento/luma
```

[Source](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-deploy-static-content-theme/)

Comment: Shouldnt there be a `-l` before the `en_US` ?

Comment: `php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -l en_AU -a frontend -t Lowes/b2b` That did the trick for me. The only thing I noticed is, it deploys parent themes too.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that by now you have to deploy any language except en_US manually.
i am working with 2.0.2 and develop-branch.

Comment: You sir, are correct.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy an specific theme with an specific language:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend --theme Vendor/mytheme pt_BR`

Answer (score 1):

If your magento is in developer mode then deploy specific theme using below commands :

Remove static content

```
rm -rf pub/static/*                            /*to remove files excluding .htaccess*/

rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*                 /*to remove files excluding .htaccess*/
```

And then

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Vendor/theme
```

OR

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f --theme Vendor/theme
```