# Magento 2 deploy static files for specific theme only

Tags: magento2, php, deploy

How to deploy static view files for single, specific theme only?

Comment: I'm talking about production mode, when static files not synch automatically, also Grunt deploy only .less/.css/.js/images files and ignore mosts of other files. Basically there is many cases when you need to re-run hp bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Yes, this is **not** a duplicate question, and the provided answer is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

In version 2.1 Magento extended static files deployment script significantly, so it’s more advanced and flexible now. You can not just specify theme or area, but also do not deploy css/less/images/html files and much more. If you want to use all features please update your Magento version and checkout [2.1 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)

**If you already using Magento 2.1 version, please ignore this article**

**Introduction**

As we know from [Magento 2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict) in production mode wanting to deploy static files you must log in to server and using console run command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. This command will deploy static files for all available designs, such as `frontend -> Magento/blank`, `frontend -> Magento/luma` as well as `adminhtml -> Magento/backend` and your custom design. 
This process is quite slow, especially if your theme parenting or is child of another theme. Unfortunately there is no much options for deploy command available - you could set language code in ISO format like:
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US` and basically that's it.

**Let's play around and create extended version.**

1. Create command `app/code/Vortex/Summit/Console/Command/Deploy/DeployStaticContentCommand.php`

```php
<?php
namespace Vortex\Summit\Console\Command\Deploy;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Validator\Locale;
/**
 * Command for deploy static content
 */
class DeployStaticContentCommand extends Command
{
    const THEME_OPTION = 'theme';
    /**
     * Key for dry-run option
     */
    const DRY_RUN_OPTION = 'dry-run';
    /**
     * Key for languages parameter
     */
    const LANGUAGE_OPTION = 'languages';
    /**
     * @var Locale
     */
    private $validator;
    /**
     * Factory to get object manager
     *
     * @var ObjectManagerFactory
     */
    private $objectManagerFactory;
    /**
     * object manager to create various objects
     *
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     *
     */
    private $objectManager;
    /**
     * Inject dependencies
     *
     * @param ObjectManagerFactory $objectManagerFactory
     * @param Locale $validator
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManagerFactory $objectManagerFactory,
        Locale $validator,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->objectManagerFactory = $objectManagerFactory;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('setup:static-content:deploy-extended')
            ->setDescription('Deploy static view files [-t for specific theme only]')
            ->setDefinition([
                new InputOption(
                    self::DRY_RUN_OPTION,
                    '-d',
                    InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
                    'If specified, then no files will be actually deployed.'
                ),
                new InputOption(
                    self::THEME_OPTION,
                    '-t',
                    InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
                    'Deploy specific theme'
                ),
                new InputArgument(
                    self::LANGUAGE_OPTION,
                    InputArgument::IS_ARRAY,
                    'List of languages you want the tool populate files for.',
                    ['en_US']
                )
            ]);
        parent::configure();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $options = $input->getOptions();
        $languages = $input->getArgument(self::LANGUAGE_OPTION);
        foreach ($languages as $lang) {
            if (!$this->validator->isValid($lang)) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                    $lang . ' argument has invalid value, please run info:language:list for list of available locales'
                );
            }
        }
        try {
            // run the deployment logic
            $filesUtil = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Utility\Files');
            $deployer = $this->objectManager->create(
                'Vortex\Summit\Model\Deploy\Deployer',
                ['filesUtil' => $filesUtil, 'output' => $output, 'isDryRun' => $options[self::DRY_RUN_OPTION], 'themeToDeploy' => $options[self::THEME_OPTION]]
            );
            $deployer->deploy($this->objectManagerFactory, $languages);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln('<error>' . $e->getMessage() . '</error>>');
            if ($output->getVerbosity() >= OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_VERBOSE) {
                $output->writeln($e->getTraceAsString());
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create Deployer model `app/code/Vortex/Summit/Model/Deploy/Deployer.php`

```php
<?php
namespace Vortex\Summit\Model\Deploy;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContentProcessorException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\AlternativeSourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\View\Deployment\Version;
use Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher;
use Magento\Framework\App\Utility\Files;
use Magento\Framework\Config\Theme;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Js\Config as JsTranslationConfig;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
/**
 * A service for deploying Magento static view files for production mode
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
 */
class Deployer extends \Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer
{
    /** @var Files */
    private $filesUtil;
    /** @var ObjectManagerFactory */
    private $omFactory;
    /** @var OutputInterface */
    private $output;
    /** @var Version\StorageInterface */
    private $versionStorage;
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository */
    private $assetRepo;
    /** @var Publisher */
    private $assetPublisher;
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Bundle\Manager */
    private $bundleManager;
    /** @var bool */
    private $isDryRun;
    /** @var int */
    private $count;
    /** @var int */
    private $errorCount;
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Template\Html\MinifierInterface */
    private $htmlMinifier;
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    private $objectManager;
    /**
     * @var JsTranslationConfig
     */
    protected $jsTranslationConfig;
    /**
     * @var AlternativeSourceInterface[]
     */
    private $alternativeSources;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $themeToDeploy;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Files $filesUtil
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     * @param Version\StorageInterface $versionStorage
     * @param JsTranslationConfig $jsTranslationConfig
     * @param AlternativeSourceInterface[] $alternativeSources
     * @param bool $isDryRun
     */
    public function __construct(
        Files $filesUtil,
        OutputInterface $output,
        Version\StorageInterface $versionStorage,
        JsTranslationConfig $jsTranslationConfig,
        array $alternativeSources,
        $isDryRun = false,
        $themeToDeploy = ''
    ) {
        $this->filesUtil = $filesUtil;
        $this->output = $output;
        $this->versionStorage = $versionStorage;
        $this->isDryRun = $isDryRun;
        $this->themeToDeploy = $themeToDeploy;
        $this->jsTranslationConfig = $jsTranslationConfig;
        $this->parentTheme = [];
        array_map(
            function (AlternativeSourceInterface $alternative) {
            },
            $alternativeSources
        );
        $this->alternativeSources = $alternativeSources;
    }
    /**
     * Populate all static view files for specified root path and list of languages
     *
     * @param ObjectManagerFactory $omFactory
     * @param array $locales
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function deploy(ObjectManagerFactory $omFactory, array $locales)
    {
        $this->omFactory = $omFactory;
        if ($this->isDryRun) {
            $this->output->writeln('Dry run. Nothing will be recorded to the target directory.');
        }
        $langList = implode(', ', $locales);
        $this->output->writeln("Requested languages: {$langList}");
        $libFiles = $this->filesUtil->getStaticLibraryFiles();
        list($areas, $appFiles) = $this->collectAppFiles($locales);
        foreach ($areas as $area => $themes) {
            $this->emulateApplicationArea($area);
            foreach ($locales as $locale) {
                $this->emulateApplicationLocale($locale, $area);
                foreach ($themes as $themePath) {
                    if ($this->themeToDeploy && !strpos($themePath, '/' . $this->themeToDeploy)) continue;
                    $this->output->writeln("=== {$area} -> {$themePath} -> {$locale} ===");
                    $this->count = 0;
                    $this->errorCount = 0;
                    /** @var \Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design $design */
                    $design = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design');
                    $design->setDesignTheme($themePath, $area);
                    $assetRepo = $this->objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository',
                        [
                            'design' => $design,
                        ]
                    );
                    /** @var \Magento\RequireJs\Model\FileManager $fileManager */
                    $fileManager = $this->objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\RequireJs\Model\FileManager',
                        [
                            'config' => $this->objectManager->create(
                                'Magento\Framework\RequireJs\Config',
                                [
                                    'assetRepo' => $assetRepo,
                                    'design' => $design,
                                ]
                            ),
                            'assetRepo' => $assetRepo,
                        ]
                    );
                    $fileManager->createRequireJsConfigAsset();
                    foreach ($appFiles as $info) {
                        list($fileArea, $fileTheme, , $module, $filePath) = $info;
                        if (($fileArea == $area || $fileArea == 'base') &&
                            ($fileTheme == '' || $fileTheme == $themePath ||
                                in_array(
                                    $fileArea . Theme::THEME_PATH_SEPARATOR . $fileTheme,
                                    $this->findAncestors($area . Theme::THEME_PATH_SEPARATOR . $themePath)
                                ))
                        ) {
                            $compiledFile = $this->deployFile($filePath, $area, $themePath, $locale, $module);
                            if ($compiledFile !== '') {
                                $this->deployFile($compiledFile, $area, $themePath, $locale, $module);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    foreach ($libFiles as $filePath) {
                        $compiledFile = $this->deployFile($filePath, $area, $themePath, $locale, null);
                        if ($compiledFile !== '') {
                            $this->deployFile($compiledFile, $area, $themePath, $locale, null);
                        }
                    }
                    if ($this->jsTranslationConfig->dictionaryEnabled()) {
                        $this->deployFile(
                            $this->jsTranslationConfig->getDictionaryFileName(),
                            $area,
                            $themePath,
                            $locale,
                            null
                        );
                    }
                    $fileManager->clearBundleJsPool();
                    $this->bundleManager->flush();
                    $this->output->writeln("\nSuccessful: {$this->count} files; errors: {$this->errorCount}\n---\n");
                }
            }
        }
        $this->output->writeln('=== Minify templates ===');
        $this->count = 0;
        foreach ($this->filesUtil->getPhtmlFiles(false, false) as $template) {
            $this->htmlMinifier->minify($template);
            if ($this->output->getVerbosity() >= OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_VERBOSE) {
                $this->output->writeln($template . " minified\n");
            } else {
                $this->output->write('.');
            }
            $this->count++;
        }
        $this->output->writeln("\nSuccessful: {$this->count} files modified\n---\n");
        $version = (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp();
        $this->output->writeln("New version of deployed files: {$version}");
        if (!$this->isDryRun) {
            $this->versionStorage->save($version);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Accumulate all static view files in the application and record all found areas, themes and languages
     *
     * Returns an array of areas and files with meta information
     *
     * @param array $requestedLocales
     * @return array
     */
    private function collectAppFiles($requestedLocales)
    {
        $areas = [];
        $locales = [];
        $files = $this->filesUtil->getStaticPreProcessingFiles();
        foreach ($files as $info) {
            list($area, $themePath, $locale) = $info;
            if ($themePath) {
                $areas[$area][$themePath] = $themePath;
            }
            if ($locale) {
                $locales[$locale] = $locale;
            }
        }
        foreach ($requestedLocales as $locale) {
            unset($locales[$locale]);
        }
        if (!empty($locales)) {
            $langList = implode(', ', $locales);
            $this->output->writeln(
                "WARNING: there were files for the following languages detected in the file system: {$langList}."
                . ' These languages were not requested, so the files will not be populated.'
            );
        }
        return [$areas, $files];
    }
    /**
     * Emulate application area and various services that are necessary for populating files
     *
     * @param string $areaCode
     * @return void
     */
    private function emulateApplicationArea($areaCode)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $this->omFactory->create(
            [\Magento\Framework\App\State::PARAM_MODE => \Magento\Framework\App\State::MODE_DEFAULT]
        );
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState */
        $appState = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $appState->setAreaCode($areaCode);
        $this->assetRepo = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository');
        $this->assetPublisher = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher');
        $this->htmlMinifier = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Template\Html\MinifierInterface');
        $this->bundleManager = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Bundle\Manager');
    }
    /**
     * Set application locale and load translation for area
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $area
     * @return void
     */
    protected function emulateApplicationLocale($locale, $area)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\TranslateInterface $translator */
        $translator = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\TranslateInterface');
        $translator->setLocale($locale);
        $translator->loadData($area, true);
    }
    /**
     * Deploy a static view file
     *
     * @param string $filePath
     * @param string $area
     * @param string $themePath
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $module
     * @return string
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    private function deployFile($filePath, $area, $themePath, $locale, $module)
    {
        $compiledFile = '';
        $extension = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        foreach ($this->alternativeSources as $name => $alternative) {
            if (in_array($extension, $alternative->getAlternativesExtensionsNames(), true)
                && strpos(basename($filePath), '_') !== 0
            ) {
                $compiledFile = substr($filePath, 0, strlen($filePath) - strlen($extension) - 1);
                $compiledFile = $compiledFile . '.' . $name;
            }
        }
        if ($this->output->isVeryVerbose()) {
            $logMessage = "Processing file '$filePath' for area '$area', theme '$themePath', locale '$locale'";
            if ($module) {
                $logMessage .= ", module '$module'";
            }
            $this->output->writeln($logMessage);
        }
        try {
            $asset = $this->assetRepo->createAsset(
                $filePath,
                ['area' => $area, 'theme' => $themePath, 'locale' => $locale, 'module' => $module]
            );
            if ($this->output->isVeryVerbose()) {
                $this->output->writeln("\tDeploying the file to '{$asset->getPath()}'");
            } else {
                $this->output->write('.');
            }
            if ($this->isDryRun) {
                $asset->getContent();
            } else {
                $this->assetPublisher->publish($asset);
                $this->bundleManager->addAsset($asset);
            }
            $this->count++;
        } catch (ContentProcessorException $exception) {
            throw $exception;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->output->write('.');
            $this->verboseLog($exception->getTraceAsString());
            $this->errorCount++;
        }
        return $compiledFile;
    }
    /**
     * Find ancestor themes' full paths
     *
     * @param string $themeFullPath
     * @return string[]
     */
    private function findAncestors($themeFullPath)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ListInterface $themeCollection */
        $themeCollection = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ListInterface');
        $theme = $themeCollection->getThemeByFullPath($themeFullPath);
        $ancestors = $theme->getInheritedThemes();
        $ancestorThemeFullPath = [];
        foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
            $ancestorThemeFullPath[] = $ancestor->getFullPath();
        }
        return $ancestorThemeFullPath;
    }
    /**
     * Verbose log
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @return void
     */
    private function verboseLog($message)
    {
        if ($this->output->isVerbose()) {
            $this->output->writeln($message);
        }
    }
}
```

(I guess this model could be extended from default Magento class so you will not need to override all methods)

3. Register new command in `app/code/Vortex/Summit/etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="summitDeployCommand" xsi:type="object">Vortex\Summit\Console\Command\Deploy\DeployStaticContentCommand</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

4. Clear cache by `php bin/magento cache:flush` and check available commands `php bin/magento --list`. If everything goes well, then in commands list next to `magento setup:static-content:deploy` you should see command **`setup:static-content:deploy-extended`**
5. Now to deploy static view files for specific theme only, run:

```php
setup:static-content:deploy-extended --theme=<themename>
```

> Note: It is assumed that all required module files already exist and
>   module installed/enabled itself( in our case module - Vortex/Summit)
>   Read more about module architecture in [Vortex blog](http://www.vortexcommerce.com/blog/magento-2-module-architecture/)
>
> This method allow you to extend Magento 2 functionality without
>   changing core files.