# How to Deploy Child Theme in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme

How should I deploy child theme?

Shell, I deploy only child theme or should I do both child and parent, if so what's the correct order?

Comment: if you deploy only child theme, then there may be broken html (if child theme using  layout/template from parent theme)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you are able to content deploy specific themes by this commands:

Content Deploy specific themes By this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Vendor/firsttheme
```

For more details you can refer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101131/magento2-how-can-i-deploy-my-theme-only)